# Pulling out data from an arraylist and saving it

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the data I have saved into my array list. I want to take the id and questions I have saved in there and save them separately. Is this possible? For example my array list of objects is this

```
List<Observation> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

In it I save an Int and a boolean array. So it looks like {1 , true}. Is it possible to extract each data and save them separately? id like to save the ID part in its own int. and the boolean in a array.

ok hopefully i can explain this better. the entries list i have saves 2 forms of data for me. and int which is an id and a boolean array of true of false answers to some question. Id like take the data out and save them separately. so like id like to save the ID into a something like int idData and save the array of booleans into an array . so i can send this data to an api. the api only takes an ints and an arraylist.

so im trying to split the entries data up and save them separate because i need to send this data to an api that accepts an int and a arraylist. which is an ID and answers (array of booleans). so i need to split the entries array list i made and take out the id and boolean array and save them seperatley so i can send em.

Comment: This question does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I think it is quite unclear what you mean here.
Do you want to save the list into a file?
Do you want to extract the data from Observation that is a boolean and an int to two seperate lists?
Are you looking for a Map?

Comment: please give an example input (java code) with at least 2 elements in the "boolean array" and expected output.

Comment: @fillpant i edited my post , hopefully its a little more clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
      List<Observation> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    //Create two seperate lists as per your requirement.
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Boolean> status = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<entries.size();i++){
      Observation observation = entries.get(i);
      ids.add(observation.getId());  //Here get integer from your Observation object
      ids.add(observation.getStatus());  //Here get boolean value from your Observation object.
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks , now i see how i can do this with modifying your code.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find two possible solutions for the problem.

### Using paralel Lists

```
List<Observation> items= new ArrayList<>();
List<Integers> idList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Boolean[]> answersList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Observation o : items){
        idList.add(o.getID());
        answersList.add(o.getAnswers());
    }
```

At this point you got two List objects that are paralel. Removing one element from one of them without doing the same for the other will mess the order of data.

### Using a Map

I would recomend using a Map instead of two paralel Lists because under my opinion, its much more practical, easier, and looks better. If you plan to use a Map, you can do the following:

```
List<Observation> items= new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer,Boolean[]> data = new HashMap<>();
    for(Observation o : items)
        data.put(o.getID(),o.getAnswers());
```

And then you can use the methods comming with Map and more specifically HashMap (unless you choose anotherimplementation) to manipulate data as you please.